# Correspondence theorem for ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces, algebras

**Theorem.**
*Let $A$ be an algebra and $I\subseteq A$ be an ideal. There is a one-to-one correspondence between the ideals of $A$ containing $I$ and the ideals of $A/I$.*

Take quotient map $\pi: A \to A/I$. It's straightforward to check that

- The image of an ideal (containing $I$) in $A$  under $\pi$ is an ideal in $A/I$.
- The preimage of an ideal in $A/I$ under $\pi$ is an ideal in $A$.

So $\pi$ allows us to obtain a surjective map $\pi':\{\text{Ideals in } A \text{ that contain } I\}\to \{\text{Ideals in } A/I\}$.

**Main question.** Why is $\pi'$ a bijection? The main obstruction I have in mind is that for an ideal $K'\in A/I$, the preimage $K:=\pi^{-1}(K')$ is an ideal -- *but what is preventing the existence of a subideal $J\subseteq K$ satisfying $\pi(J)=K'$?*

> **Minor question.** Is the specification that ideals $K$ in $A$ contain $I$ just to guarantee that $\mathbf{0}\in\pi(K)$ in the construction, hence ensuring that $\pi(K)$ is a subvector space -- or is it achieving something extra?

Comment: Suppose $I\subseteq J$. If $J\ne K$ then there is an element of one that is not in the other, say $j\in J\setminus K$. Then $\pi(j)=\pi(k)$ for some $k\in K$. Then $j-k\in I$, but then $j=(j-k)+k\in I+K=K$, a contradiction. Note $\pi(K)$ is an ideal of $A/I$ for all ideals $K$ of $A$. This does not require $K$ to contain $I$. But the hypothesis that the $K$s we speak of all contain $I$ ensures that $\pi$ is a *bijection*. In general, $\pi(K_1)=\pi(K_2)$ iff $K_1+I=K_2=I$, in other words to ideals are equal "mod $I$." Distinct ideals containing $I$ are also distinct "mod $I$."

Comment: @runway44 I'd gotten to $j-k\in I$ and stopped for no good reason! Thank you for finishing this off, that's exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for your clarification on the 'minor question' too, this is now clear.

Comment: This is really a fact about the correspondence theorem for groups - which I think is possible to understand quite intuitively. Each (additive) subgroup of $A$ containing $I$ is a union of some cosets of $I$, and the map we have sends it to the set of cosets contained in it (which is a subgroup of the quotient by $I$). This map is clearly injective, because we can recover the subgroup we started with from the set of cosets of $I$ that are contained in it - just take the union of those cosets. This picture of cosets is why it's important that $I$ is contained in the subgroup!

Comment: Also... I'm not convinced that your two "straightforward" bullet points show that $\pi$ induces a surjection $\pi'$. For instance, the constant map $K \mapsto 0 + I$ also satisfies your two bullet points, but does not induce such a surjection! In general the image of a preimage of a set needn't be equal to that set.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Specifically, the surjection is from preimages of ideals in $A/I$ back onto those ideals.